# MS-Access - Open a form from a hyperlink data click

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a table and number of forms in my access database.The table has a column of type hyperlink. When i click a value in this column, one of my form in the database should be opened .

How can i proceed?

Comment: A Form from a table? What exactly is your system about? Why are you giving users access to tables directly?

Comment: Don't do this. You could use the table to populate buttons, or use a continuous subform however.

Comment: Users wont be given access ... Instead i will create a form on this table. All values in the table including hyperlink data will be displayed on tis form. When the user clicks this data, another form should be opened... that's what my query

Comment: @PaulFrancis Hope u got my question. any idea pls

Comment: @RamKumar - You need to create a Form, on which you will have the fields as control. So when you click you can code to open a Form using the DoCmd.OpenForm method.

Comment: @PaulFrancis opening a form using hyperlink is not possible?

Comment: As I mentioned, you need to "CODE" the control to open the Form, Hyperlink or not, coding can make all things possible. I'd suggest you to edit your post with a bit more information, so people would not vote down your post.

Comment: Two suggested reads: 1. ["What have you tried?"](http://whathaveyoutried.com) 2. ["The Ten Commandmnets of Access"](http://access.mvps.org/access/tencommandments.htm)

Answer (score 1):

First off, you shouldn't give your users access to the tables in your database.

Create a form, in datasheet view, based on the table. This allows you to control what your users can do with the data; under *Form Properties* -> *Data* you can choose whether users can  add, edit, delete and filter the records.

The second form, which is to be opened from the first, should be set up so that the user cannot add records or move between them; ie. no Record Selectors and no Navigation Buttons.

I would advise against using the Hyperlink field type for this, it is not what it is designed for. The Hyperlink field type is for linking to external files, either local or online -- not for navigation around the current database. Use whatever field type best suits the data in the field.

Instead, I would assign an **On Dbl Click** event to the field you wish to use for linking to the form. Open the datasheet form. Switch to design view, open the property sheet for the form and set *HasModule* (under *Other*) to **Yes** to allow use of VBA on this datasheet form.

Open the property sheet for the field, and under *Event* click the three dots by *On Dbl Click*, then *Code Builder*.

We now must add code to open the other form (showing a single record) at the correct record. This will look something like the following:

```
Private Sub [field to double click]_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)

'When [field to double click] is double clicked, open [single-record form name] at record
DoCmd.OpenForm "[single-record form name]", , , "[unique field] = " & Me![unique field]

End Sub
```

Two things should be noted here:

1. The field to be double clicked does not have to be the field that the record is selected with. In fact, you could put similar code on each field so that, wherever the user double clicks on the record, the other form is opened.
2. The [unique field] must be unique to each record for this to work properly. I'd use an autonumber ID field.